# How to Read A String Literal Stored in a Variable

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, string-literals, os.path

I was wondering if there was a way to read a string literal stored in a variable. I was essentially trying to extract the file name for a variable containing a file path. I'm aware that you need to place r' before the path name. In my example below, the variable I'm trying to update is 'test'. So basically I'm unaware of how I can use r' on the variable name to avoid parts of the path being read as unicode characters. Is there a way to do this?

```
test='NAI\site_summaries\410_-_407_Central'
head,tail=os.path.split(test)
print(tail)
```

The code above returns 'site_summaries_-_407_Central', where it should be returning '410_-_407_Central'. Please keep in mind that I have a variable containing a list of these paths but I just chose to show one path for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Maybe test.split("\")[-1] ?

Comment: It's not Unicode: `\410` is octal and it gets converted to `\010` which is the same as `\x08`, the backspace character. You need to use raw literal strings with the leading `r` if you don't want that to happen. You can't really add "rawness" to a string after you've put it into a variable.

Comment: If `'NAI\site_summaries\410_-_407_Central'` is a literal in your Python script it's broken. You need to change it either to a raw string `r'NAI\site_summaries\410_-_407_Central'` or you need to backslash-escape the backslashes: `'NAI\\site_summaries\\410_-_407_Central'`. But if it's _not_ a literal, but is instead some data your script has read, then we have a different question.